# Basic authentication with play2-auth in Play 2.5.x

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In the example below, the intent is to build a simple `play2-auth` program  that authenticates a user keeps a session until they log out.

Problem is that I get the following compilation error in `ManageSession.scala`:

> object creation impossible, since: it has 6 unimplemented members

This is the source code, I took the sample from `play2-auth` website and simplified, but the function signatures are the same:

AuthConfigImpl.scala:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.reflect._
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
import play.api.http.Status
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import jp.t2v.lab.play2.auth._

trait AuthConfigImpl extends AuthConfig {

  type Id = String
  type User = Account
  val idTag: ClassTag[Id] = classTag[Id]
  val sessionTimeoutInSeconds: Int = 3600

  def loginSucceeded(request: RequestHeader): Result = Redirect("/main",Status.OK)
  def logoutSucceeded(request: RequestHeader): Result = Redirect("/main",Status.OK)
  def authenticationFailed(request: RequestHeader): Result = Redirect("/main",Status.OK)
  def authorizationFailed(request: RequestHeader): Result = Forbidden("no permission")
  def authorize(user: User, authority: Authority): Boolean = true

//override lazy val cookieSecureOption: Boolean = 
//  play.api.Play.current.configuration.getBoolean("auth.cookie.secure").getOrElse(true)

}
```

ManageSession.scala:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import jp.t2v.lab.play2.auth._

object ManageSession extends Controller with LoginLogout with AuthConfigImpl {

  val loginForm = Form {
    mapping("email" -> email, "password" -> text)(Account.authenticate)
    (_.map(u => (u.email, "")))
      .verifying("Invalid email or password", result => result.isDefined)
  }

  def login = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.showlogin())
  }

  def logout = Action { implicit request =>
    //gotoLogoutSucceeded
    Ok("logged out")
  }

  def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
    loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.showlogin()),
      user => Ok("logged in") // gotoLoginSucceeded(user.get.email)
    )
  }
}
```

Account.scala:

```
case class Account(id: Int, email: String, password: String, name: String)

object Account  {

  def authenticate(email: String, password: String): Option[Account] = {
      if (email == "test")
          Some(Account (1, "test", "abc", "Paul"))
      else
          None
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gotoLoginSucceeded` and `gotoLogoutSucceeded` in play2-auth return `Future[Result]`, but `Action` expects a `Result`. You can fix this by using `Action.async`:

```
def logout = Action.async { implicit request =>
  // do something...
  gotoLogoutSucceeded
}

import scala.concurrent.Future

def authenticate = Action.async { implicit request =>
  loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.showlogin())),
    user => gotoLoginSucceeded(user.get.id)
  )
}
```

The same must be done with your `AuthConfig`. All of these methods are expected to return `Future[Result]`. For example

```
def loginSucceeded(request: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = 
    Future.successful(Redirect("/main", Status.OK))
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting an error in ManageSession declaration: `object creation impossible, since: it has 6 unimplemented members. /** As seen from object ManageSession, the missing signatures are as follows. * For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations. */ def authenticationFailed(request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)(implicit context: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext): scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result] = ??? def authorizationFailed(request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader,user: session.ManageSession.User,authority: Option[session.ManageSession.Authority])...`

Comment: The ExecutionContext was missing. This is how it should be defined: `def loginSucceeded(request: RequestHeader)(implicit context: ExecutionContext): Future[Result] = 
    Future.successful(Redirect("/main", Status.OK))`